# How would I get the current time every minute when an email is sent and display that time in the body of the email?

Tags: python

I am new to python and I am struggling with the datetime module and the time.sleep() method. With my current code, whenever I call my time.sleep(60) the email is sent every minute, but the updated date and time is not sent in the body of the email, it is the same time from when I originally ran the code. For example if I run the code at 6:45 pm,  after 12 minutes the body of the email should "Sat Aug 13 06:57:00 2022", instead it still says "Sat Aug 13 06:45:00 2022". Here is the code i am running:

```
import time

def send_logs():
    count = 0

    fromAddr = "example@outlook.com"
    fromPswd = "example"
    toAddr = "example@outlook.com"
  
    time.sleep(60)  #sends email every minute
    while True:
        if len(data) > 1:
            try:
                write_file(count)

                subject = f'[{user}] ~ {count}'

                msg = MIMEMultipart()
                msg['From'] = fromAddr
                msg['To'] = toAddr
                msg['Subject'] = subject
                body = f' *~ Date/Time: {datetime}\n' #body of the email, where the time is shown
                msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

                attachment = open(delete_file[0], 'rb')
                print('attachment')
                filename = delete_file[0].split('/')[2]

                part = MIMEBase('application', 'octect-stream')
                part.set_payload((attachment).read())
                encoders.encode_base64(part)
                part.add_header('content-disposition', 'attachment;filename=' + str(filename))
                msg.attach(part)

                text = msg.as_string()
                print('test msg.as_string')

                s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.office365.com', 587)
                s.ehlo()
                s.starttls()
                print('starttls')
                s.ehlo()
                s.login(fromAddr, fromPswd)
                s.sendmail(fromAddr, toAddr, text)
                print('sent mail')
                attachment.close()
                s.close()

                count += 1
                time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: where are the values of `datetime` (and `user`, for that matter) assigned?

Comment: @PierreD  the value of date time is : datetime = time.ctime(time.time()). The user, is finding a path from my pc to put my file it.

Comment: the key is where that assignment is made. If it is outside your loop, that would explain the behavior you describe. Please see if my answer helps. Also, `datetime` is a module. Try to avoid clobbering it with a variable. That confuses everything and is troublesome if you also try to use the module itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to assign a string representing the time "now" (i.e., at the time of execution of that line), replace your `body` assignment with, for example:

```py
body = f' *~ Date/Time {datetime.now():%c}\n'
```

and add this import at the beginning:

```py
from datetime import datetime
```

`'%c'` is just the format that gives the locale’s appropriate date and time representation. For all formats available, see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes).

You can of course customize it to your liking, e.g.:

```py
>>> f'{datetime.now():%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S (%a)}'
'2022-08-13 12:14:09 (Sat)'
```